# Tuple assignment not working inside try/catch

Tags: scala

I've been trying to perform a `try/catch` around one function that returns a tuple (couple of two values).

This version does NOT work:

```
var a = 0
var b = 0
try {
  (a, b) = my_function(input)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => println("Exception caught: " + e)
}
```

Whereas this one works:

```
var a = 0
var b = 0
try {
  val tmp = my_function(input)
  a = tmp._1
  b = tmp._2
} catch {
  case e: Exception => println("Exception caught: " + e)
}
```

I want to emphasize that `(a, b) = my_function(input)` works outside of the `try/catch` statement.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: "I want to emphasize that (a, b) = my_function(input) works outside of the try/catch statement." I don't believe you. Please post the code with `(a, b) = my_function(input)` that compiles.

Comment: `val (x1, x2) = my_function(12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `var`.

I don't know what `my_function` is in your example, but here's a mockup of a try/catch working with tuples:

```
// Tries to turn the input to an Int and return (input.toInt, input.toInt * 2)
def myfunction(input: String): (Int, Int) = {
  (input.toInt, input.toInt * 2)
}

// Will succeed as "4".toInt does not fail
val (a, b): (Int, Int) = try {
  myfunction("4")
} catch {
  case e: NumberFormatException =>
    throw new NumberFormatException(s"Exception caught: $e")
}
// a: Int = 4
// b: Int = 8

// Will throw an exception as "string".toInt is not possible
val (c, d): (Int, Int) = try {
  myfunction("string")
} catch {
  case e: NumberFormatException =>
    throw new NumberFormatException(s"Exception caught: ${e.getMessage}")
}
// java.lang.NumberFormatException: Exception caught: For input string: "string"
```

---

**EDIT**

Scala does have its own `Try` method, demonstrated below:

```
val (e, f): (Int, Int) = Try {
  myfunction("4")
} match {
  case Success((x, y)) => (x, y)
  case Failure(ex: NumberFormatException) =>
    throw new NumberFormatException(s"Exception caught: ${ex.getMessage}")
  case Failure(ex) =>
    throw new Exception(s"Unexpected exception: ${ex.getMessage}")
}
// e: Int = 4
// f: Int = 8

val (g, h): (Int, Int) = Try {
  myfunction("string")
} match {
  case Success((x, y)) => (x, y)
  case Failure(ex: NumberFormatException) =>
    throw new NumberFormatException(s"Exception caught: ${ex.getMessage}")
  case Failure(ex) =>
    throw new Exception(s"Unexpected exception: ${ex.getMessage}")
}
// java.lang.NumberFormatException: Exception caught: For input string: "string"
```

Comment: which one would you prefer between `try/catch` and `Try/match`?

Comment: I'm employed as a Scala developer, so I have taught myself to try to use Scala methods of doing things where possible. It's all about what you're most comfortable using. I personally like how you can get the variable names out of the `Success` block as shown in my example, and I like how these `Try/Success/Failure` blocks can be relatively small as a result. I also prefer how they read, without the `case e: Exception =>` part being repeated all over the place and with the "this can either be a Success or Failure" syntax. I guess it's just my personal preference though.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to emphasize that (a, b) = my_function(input) works outside of the try/catch statement.

It doesn't. If you do *the same thing without `try`*

```
var a = 0
var b = 0
(a, b) = my_function(input)
```

you'll see it doesn't work, so `try` isn't relevant. What you call "tuple assignment" is a special case of pattern matching, and it only works to introduce *new* `val`s or `var`s, not to assign to existing ones.

But because `try/catch` is an expression, you can do

```
val (a, b) = try {
  my_function(input)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => 
    println("Exception caught: " + e)
    (0, 0)
}
```

Note that the type of `try/catch` is the common supertype of `try` and `catch` parts.